# How to delete image from storage in restfull api

Tags: laravel

```
  $employee = Employee::find($id);
        Storage::delete($employee->photo_file_path . $employee->photo_file_type);
        $file = $request->image;
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/images', $id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $employee->photo_file_name = $id;
        $employee->photo_file_type = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $employee->photo_file_path = $path;
```

when uploading photos, I want the previous photo to be deleted first and then insert a new photo again, I use Storage::delete. I have checked the public folder but the previous photo was not deleted, instead the photo was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading images in public folder then you need to add public before your path

```
Storage::delete('public/'.$employee->photo_file_path . $employee->photo_file_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

if(file_exists(public_path('upload/bio.png'))){unlink(public_path('upload/bio.png'));
}else{dd('File does not exists.');}